# Remove rows with overlapping date ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with start_date and end_date columns and I want to remove records where both start_date and end_date are in an existing date range

source data:

```
start_date                  end_date
2019-03-18 00:00:00.000     2019-04-08 00:00:00.000
2019-04-01 00:00:00.000     2019-05-31 00:00:00.000
2019-04-03 00:00:00.000     2019-04-24 00:00:00.000
2019-04-24 00:00:00.000     2019-05-05 00:00:00.000
2019-05-06 00:00:00.000     2019-05-16 00:00:00.000
2019-05-06 00:00:00.000     2019-05-20 00:00:00.000
2019-05-06 00:00:00.000     2019-06-17 00:00:00.000
2019-05-10 00:00:00.000     2019-05-14 00:00:00.000
```

expected result:

```
start_date                  end_date
2019-03-18 00:00:00.000     2019-04-08 00:00:00.000
2019-04-01 00:00:00.000     2019-05-31 00:00:00.000
2019-05-06 00:00:00.000     2019-06-17 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's really not that hard, you just check for literally the thing you want to check for. Simply verify there aren't any records that would would contain your start date and end date between their own start and end date.

Something like this will work:

```
select * 
  from so_58088216 wrapping
 where not exists (select * 
                     from so_58088216 wrapped 
                    where wrapping.start_date between wrapped.start_date and wrapped.end_date 
                      and wrapping.end_date between wrapped.start_date and wrapped.end_date
                      -- don't check against yourself, this would be easier if had an ID or something
                      and wrapping.start_date != wrapped.start_date 
                      and wrapping.end_date != wrapped.end_date)
```

[Here's a working example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=57519e234c18f4ade07ecd87c1e8f5e8)